# How do I use MemoryFailPoint?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

A [`MemoryFailPoint` (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "*checks for sufficient memory resources before executing an operation."*

But how is it actually used correctly?

Does the `MemoryFailPoint` automatically reserve some memory for the next big object I create? Or does it simply check whether the memory would be free, without reserving it?

Does it check physical memory, physical memory plus page file, virtual address space, or something else entirely?

When do I dispose it? Do I need to dispose the `MemoryFailPoint` before actually creating the memory-hungry object, or must I create the object before disposing the `MemoryFailPoint`?

e.g.

```
try
{
   using (MemoryFailPoint mem = new MemoryFailPoint(500))
   {
      // allocate big object here?
   }
}
catch (InsufficientMemoryException e)
{
   // ...
}
// or allocate big object here?

// or allocate big object on another thread?
```

Can another thread within the same process steal the memory I have reserved with a `MemoryFailPoint`, or does the `MemoryFailPoint` reserve the memory exclusively for the current thread?

What happens if the `MemoryFailPoint` is not disposed? Does an undisposed `MemoryFailPoint` consume significant amounts of memory itself?

Answer (score 4):

The source code for `MemoryFailPoint` is available at [.NET Source](http://sourceof.net). The very descriptive comment at the start of the class answers your questions. I am copying that comment here for easier reference:

> This class allows an application to fail before starting certain 
>      activities.  The idea is to fail early instead of failing in the middle
>      of some long-running operation to increase the survivability of the 
>      application and ensure you don't have to write tricky code to handle an 
>      OOM anywhere in your app's code (which implies state corruption, meaning you
>      should unload the appdomain, if you have a transacted environment to ensure
>      rollback of individual transactions).  This is an incomplete tool to attempt
>      hoisting all your OOM failures from anywhere in your worker methods to one 
>      particular point where it is easier to handle an OOM failure, and you can
>      optionally choose to not start a workitem if it will likely fail.  This does 
>      not help the performance of your code directly (other than helping to avoid 
>      AD unloads).  The point is to avoid starting work if it is likely to fail.
>      The Enterprise Services team has used these memory gates effectively in the 
>      unmanaged world for a decade.
>
> In Whidbey, we will simply check to see if there is enough memory available
>      in the OS's page file & attempt to ensure there might be enough space free
>      within the process's address space (checking for address space fragmentation
>      as well).  We will not commit or reserve any memory.  To avoid ----s with
>      other threads using MemoryFailPoints, we'll also keep track of a 
>      process-wide amount of memory "reserved" via all currently-active 
>      MemoryFailPoints.  This has two problems:
>
> ```
>  1. This can account for memory twice.  If a thread creates a 
>      MemoryFailPoint for 100 MB then allocates 99 MB, we'll see 99 MB 
>      less free memory and 100 MB less reserved memory.  Yet, subtracting 
>      off the 100 MB is necessary because the thread may not have started
>      allocating memory yet.  Disposing of this class immediately after 
>      front-loaded allocations have completed is a great idea.
>  2. This is still vulnerable to ----s with other threads that don't use 
>      MemoryFailPoints.
> ```
>
> So this class is far from perfect.  But it may be good enough to 
>      meaningfully reduce the frequency of OutOfMemoryExceptions in managed apps.
>
> In Orcas or later, we might allocate some memory from the OS and add it
>      to a allocation context for this thread.  Obviously, at that point we need
>      some way of conveying when we release this block of memory.  So, we 
>      implemented IDisposable on this type in Whidbey and expect all users to call
>      this from within a using block to provide lexical scope for their memory 
>      usage.  The call to Dispose (implicit with the using block) will give us an
>      opportunity to release this memory, perhaps.  We anticipate this will give 
>      us the possibility of a more effective design in a future version.
>
> In Orcas, we may also need to differentiate between allocations that would
>      go into the normal managed heap vs. the large object heap, or we should 
>      consider checking for enough free space in both locations (with any 
>      appropriate adjustments to ensure the memory is contiguous).

Comment: Dispose is not really clear what it does. "Release this memory". What memory? I thought MemoryFailPoint  doesn't actually allocate any memory, it simply checks if it can allocate it?

Comment: Based on the comment from the source, the Dispose method is primarily there to ensure that the code can make use of the call to clean up in the future. See the second to last paragraph of the quoted section.

Comment: I am still not following what "make use of the call to clean up in the future" means. What happens if you make 1000x MemoryFailPoints all 512mb big and never dispose of them? I don't feel like I can answer that question based on the information available.

Answer (score 0):

The usage pattern is following:

```
const int sizeMB = 500;
using (MemoryFailPoint mem = new MemoryFailPoint(sizeMB))
{
   // Allocate sizeMB - large object here. The allocation is *likely* going to succeed.
}
```

When MemoryFailPoint constructor fails, there is high probability for large object allocation to throw OOM. Even when successful, it would make the process less stable to other (even smaller) memory allocation operations.

In my 16 GB Windows environment the following example generated InsufficientMemoryException one iteration earlier (step = 5) than OOM without MemoryFailPoint around array allocation code (at step = 6):

```
 List<byte[]> arrays = new List<byte[]>();
 const int size = int.MaxValue/2;
 const int sizeMB = size / 1024 / 1024;
 for(int step = 0; step < 10000; step++)
 {
     using (new MemoryFailPoint(sizeMB))
     {
         arrays.Add(new byte[size]);
     }
 }
```